Ubunti Pro Real Time - how does realtime apply to applications?
Just finished installing Ubuntu Pro with Realtime enabled.  Question is, when launching an application, does Realtime apply to the first application that was launched ?  How do we check if realtime is applied to the application - does ubuntu pro do that in the background for us?
The version we downloaded is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. We used a personal subscription number to enable pro realtime. We simply want to run one application using realtime and see if it makes a difference against a standard install of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Did you do any research? A Google search finds this info. The major advantage of using realtime is that, its deterministic nature of task execution, within expected time limits and less latency. Making it suitable for deployment in areas of Robotics in Industries, Aerospace, Multimedia and many others, that require predictable response time.23 May 2024

Since no one here works for the company, we are all volunteers this is something you may want to ask the Ubuntu Pro guys.

The version we downloaded is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.   We used a personal subscription number to enable pro realtime.   We simply want to run one application using realtime and see if it makes a difference against a standard install of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

"Realtime" is a kernel feature, not a Pro setting. The kernel will apply its low-latency rules to all applications, so it's best not to pile on too many applications. If you are testing a single application that has (seemingly) slow performance, the kernel would usually be fairly low on the troubleshooting list. Lots of ways applications can be slow.

@JoelP Anyways edit and update your question. The comments are mainly our way to ask you for clarification. Once you update the question, you may notify the person who asked for it by leaving a comment starting with @user as I have done at the beginning of this comment.
